# How to implement a decision matrix in Delphi

Tags: algorithm, delphi, dictionary, delphi-7, boolean-logic

I have to implement a decision matrix in Delphi 7.
The function is

> CalcNewStatus( actionCode: string; reportType: string; currentStatus: string): string;

- ActionCode can have the values 'A' and 'N'
- ReportType can have the values 'I' and 'F'
- CurrentStatus can have the values 'P', 'I', 'F'.

In C# I would use a dictionary, for example. How can I do this in Delphi 7?

Comment: The version is a shame... TDictionary came in Delphi 2009.

Comment: There are not enough details here. Could you elaborate.

Comment: why do you use `string` args? it is better to declare enumerations like `TActionCode = (acA, acN)`, `TReportType = (rtI, rtF)`, `TCurrentStatus = (csP, csI, csF)`, after that you can use arrays like `data : array[TActionCode] of ...` (instead of dictionary) and use it like `data[acN]`.

Comment: Perhaps some reading of [Binary Decision Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) may be helpful.

Comment: @teran: I use strings because the application receives data from a device. Your observation is correct and an intermediary step is needed to transform the strings into integer or enum values.

Comment: I like all the answers (I eventually saw the solution myself after posting the question). I'll award the answer to Mr. Rob Kennedy, as he posted a nicely implemented code. I'm sorry I can't award the answer to all replies. Thank you all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normalize your input characters to zero-based ordinal values and things become much easier. Start with a few type declarations:

```
type
  TActionCode = (acA, acN);
  TReportType = (rtI, rtF);
  TStatus = (sP, sI, sF);
```

Then you can define an array using those types with all possible status values. Replace `sX` with whichever status value belongs in each spot.

```
const
  NextStatus: array[TActionCode, TReportType, TStatus] of TStatus = (
    {acA} (// sP, sI, sF
      {rtI} ( sX, sX, sX),
      {rtF} ( sX, sX, sX)
          ),
    {acN} (
      {rtI} ( sX, sX, sX),
      {rtF} ( sX, sX, sX)
          )
  );
```

Then your function is simply this:

```
function CalcNewStatus(const actionCode, reportType, currentStatus: string): string;
var
  ac: TActionCode;
  rt: TReportType;
  s: TStatus;
const
  StateChars: array[TState] of Char = ('P', 'I', 'F');
begin
  Assert(actionCode <> ''); Assert(reportType <> ''); Assert(currentStatus <> '');
  Assert(actionCode[1] in ['A', 'N']);
  Assert(reportType[1] in ['I', 'F']);
  Assert(currentStatus[1] in ['P', 'I', 'F']);
  if actionCode[1] = 'A' then ac := acA else ac := acN;
  if reportType[1] = 'I' then rt := rtI else rt := rtF;
  if currentStatus[1] = 'P' then s := sP
  else if currentStatus[1] = 'I' then s := sI
  else s := sF;

  Result := StateChars[NextStatus[ac, rt, s]];
end;
```

As you can see, most of this code is spent converting between strings and the enum types. If you can, avoid strings in this case. Switch to the enum types as early in your program as possible, and only convert back to strings or characters when you absolutely need to. Strings can have arbitrary length, which you really shouldn't have to deal with, and strings can also have values outside the range you've defined. Enums can't, unless you do something weird. Furthermore, the compiler won't let you accidentally use a TState value where a TReportType is expected, which will help you from confusing your I's and F's.

Answer (score 4):

First of all in such a limited case (2 ActionCodes, 2 ReportTypes, 3 Statuses) I should definitely use enumerated types instead of strings.

And for the decision matrix ... a matrix:

```
Type 
  TActionCode = (taA, taN);
  TReprotType = (rtI, rtF);
  TStatus = (stP, stI, stF);

const
  NewStatus: array [TActionCode, TReportType, TStatus] of TStatus = 
        ((((,,)),((,,))),(((,,)),((,,))))    // values of the new statuses here
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution that uses a single-dimensional array.

```
unit XnResultStatusOverride;

interface

function XnCalcOverridenResultStatus(
    actionCodeStr: string;
    reportTypeStr: string;
    currentStatusStr: string ): string;


implementation

uses SysUtils;

type
TActionCodes = ( ActionCodeA = 0, ActionCodeN = 1);
TReportTypes = (ReportTypeI = 0, ReportTypeF = 1);
TResultStatus = (ResultStatusP = 0, ResultStatusF = 1, ResultStatusI = 2);

const
    DecisionMatrix: array[ 0 .. 15 ] of TResultStatus
    =
    (
      ResultStatusF, // 0 A-I-P
      ResultStatusF, // 1 A-I-F
      ResultStatusF, // 2 A-I-I
      ResultStatusF, // 3 N/A
      ResultStatusP, // 4 A-F-P
      ResultStatusP, // 5 A-F-F
      ResultStatusF, // 6 A-F-I
      ResultStatusF, // 7 N/A
      ResultStatusF, // 8 N-I-P
      ResultStatusF, // 9 N-I-F
      ResultStatusP, // 10 N-I-I
      ResultStatusF, // 11 N/A
      ResultStatusF, // 12 N-F-P
      ResultStatusI, // 13 N-F-F
      ResultStatusF, // 14 N-F-I
      ResultStatusF  // 15 N/A
    );


function ParseActionCodeString( value: string ): TActionCodes;
begin
    if value = 'A' then
    begin
        result := ActionCodeA;
        exit;
    end;

    if value = 'N' then
    begin
        result := ActionCodeN;
        exit;
    end;

    raise Exception.Create('Invalid action code string' );
end;

function ParseReportTypeString( value: string ): TReportTypes;
begin
    if value = 'I' then
    begin
        result := ReportTypeI;
        exit;
    end;

    if value = 'F' then
    begin
        result := ReportTypeF;
        exit;
    end;

    raise Exception.Create('Invalid report type string' );
end;


function ParseResultStatusString( value: string ): TResultStatus;
begin
    if value = 'P' then
    begin
        result := ResultStatusP;
        exit;
    end;

    if value = 'F' then
    begin
        result := ResultStatusF;
        exit;
    end;

    if value = 'I' then
    begin
        result := ResultStatusI;
        exit;
    end;

    raise Exception.Create('Invalid result status string' );
end;

function ResultStatusToString( value: TResultStatus ): string;
begin

    if value = ResultStatusP then
    begin
        result := 'P';
        exit;
    end;

    if value = ResultStatusF then
    begin
        result := 'F';
        exit;
    end;

    if value = ResultStatusI then
    begin
        result := 'I';
        exit;
    end;

    raise Exception.Create('Unknown TResultStatus enum member' );

end;

function XnCalcOverridenResultStatus(
    actionCodeStr: string;
    reportTypeStr: string;
    currentStatusStr: string ): string;
var
    actionCode: TActionCodes;
    reportType: TReportTypes;
    currentStatus:TResultStatus;
    discriminant: integer;
    newStatusInt: integer;
    newStatus: TResultStatus;
begin

    actionCode    := ParseActionCodeString( actionCodeStr );
    reportType    := ParseReportTypeString( reportTypeStr );
    currentStatus := ParseResultStatusString( currentStatusStr );

    discriminant  := integer(actionCode) * 8 + integer(reportType) * 4 + integer(currentStatus);

    newStatusInt  := DecisionMatrix[ discriminant ];
    newStatus     := TResultStatus( newStatusInt);

    Result        := ResultStatusToString( newStatus );

end;


end.
```